# How to embed multiple jQuery line of code in custom HtmlHelpers ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I 've tried to create my own HTML Helper which work fine for my need but I can't embed many lines
of jQuery code in my extension HtmlHelpers class. I've tried @ literal for jQuery code I doesn't work or I need to escape every line of code that I thing I not good for
multiple line of code. I don't know if there is another way to achieve this problem like <<

Therefore, I need to include jQuery plugin file and put implement script

after HTML tag. I find it would be convenience if I could put every in HTML helper and put a single line of code in aspx page for example

```
<%= Html.ParentChildSelectList(string parentName, string  childName, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> parentViewData, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> childViewData,
int parentSize, in childSize) %>
```

The following code is the way that I used now.

the .aspx page

```
<div class="CategoryContainer">
    <label for="CategoryID">
        Category
    </label>

    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)%>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", ViewData["categoryList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { size = 10 })%>
</div>

<div class="CategoryContainer">
   <%=Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubcategoryID,"subcategory") %><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubcategoryID)%>
    <%=Html.DropDownList("SubcategoryID", ViewData["subcategoryList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { size = 10 })%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.sarapadchang.parentChildSelectList(

   {
   parentId : "CategoryID" ,
   childId : "SubcategoryID",
   actionName : "GetSubcategoryList",
   controllerName : "Json"
   }

   );
   </script>
```

I put  in head tag to include ParentChildSelectList.js

the following  code for ParentChildSelectList.js

```
(function($) {

$.sarapadchang = {
    parentChildSelectList: function(options) {
        // $("#CategoryID option").click(function()

        $("#" + options.parentId).find("option").click(function() {
            $("#" + options.childId).empty(); //clear data
            $("#" + options.childId).append('<option>loading...</option>');

            $.post("/" + options.controllerName + "/" +  options.actionName + "/" + $(this).attr('value'), "", function(data) {


                var html = "";

                $.each(data, function(index, entry) {
                    html +=
           '<option value="' +
            entry['Value'] +
            '">' +
            entry['Text'] +
            '</option>';

                }
            );

                $("#" + options.childId).empty()
                $("#" + options.childId).append(html);
            }, "json"); //end getJson
        });

})(jQuery);
```

To illustrate you, I've attached simple solution, please follow this link.
http://www.thaileaguefc.net/ParentChildSelectList.rar
Please accept my apologies if my English is difficult to understand.

I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Your faithfully,
Theeranit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend embedding only a reference to your script into your HtmlHelper and keep your ParentChildSelectList.js script in the HEAD of your page.

If you need to use a string literal, remember that two quotes ("") equals a single quote ("), or use only single-quotes (') to avoid any conflicts...

```
string jScript = @"
    <script type=""text/javascript"">
            $(function() {
                var elCount = $(""body *"").size();
                alert(""You have "" + elCount + "" elements on your page"");
            });
    </script>
    ";
```